# Outputting missing dates read from a text file in c#

Tags: c#

I have a text file with a list of dates, i am supposed to read those dates and only write the missing dates to a new text file called output file. I also have to exclude weekends and holidays when writing the missing dates to the text file and write some of the dates in ranges.

Comment: You can't ask us to write a program for you. What have you tried and how are you stuck?

Comment: This is either homework or for your job, in either case, doing it for you doesn't actually help you.

Comment: I've part-answered below, but suggest you come back with a little more deatils, or hire someone at http://www.freelancer.com/

Answer (score 1):

I was a little loathed to answer this, as there appeared to be no effort on your behalf on trying to solve it. However, the code snippet below should get you going. Its very basic and rough, but works in a console app.

You still have to work out how this fits into your example, and how to read from a file and a few other items.

Point to note - it is not a simple copy/paste job.

```
//setup - you will have to read from a file - the array is for demo purposes.
var sl = new string[] { "01/12/2012", 
                        "02/12/2012", 
                        "03/12/2012", 
                        //..etc... ......my code has the full range here
                        "15/12/2012", 
                        //"16/12/2012", //commented out for demo purposes
                        "17/12/2012", 
                        //"18/12/2012", //commented out for demo purposes
                        "19/12/2012", 
                        //"20/12/2012", //commented out for demo purposes
                        //"21/12/2012", //commented out for demo purposes
                        "22/12/2012", 
                        "23/12/2012", 
                        //"24/12/2012", //commented out for demo purposes
                        "25/12/2012", 
                        //..etc... ......my code has the full range here
                        "31/12/2012" };

        DateTime nextdt, dt_start, dt_end;

        //get start and end dates and then range in days
        dt_start = DateTime.Parse(sl[0]);
        dt_end = DateTime.Parse(sl[sl.Length - 1]);
        TimeSpan range = dt_end.Subtract(dt_start);

        int j = 0;
        //loop across the range searching for missing days and filtering sturday and sunday
        for (int i=0; i<range.Days; i++)
        {
            nextdt = dt_start.AddDays(i);

            if (DateTime.Parse(sl[j]).Equals(nextdt))
            {
                j++;
            }
            else
            {
                if ( (nextdt.DayOfWeek.ToString() != "Saturday") &&
                     (nextdt.DayOfWeek.ToString() != "Sunday") )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(nextdt.ToString() + ":" + nextdt.DayOfWeek);
                }
            }
        }
```

If you are successful, can I propose you post the answer.

Comment: uhm sorry i ddnt give you more information i was still trying to figure it out myself and was trying out different methods, i ddnt have any concrete coding to give @ James Wiseman i tried using the code you gave and i have one problem, it doesnt read thewhole text file dates but only starts reading halfway from it so im still working on how i can fix that.